# How to create page in Sonata Page?

Tags: symfony, admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

I want to have site available under route `/answers`, I've made the service, twig file and remove it from fixtures from static pages. Now it disappear from Sonata Page Site Builder in CMS. 
How do I add a new page ?

Comment: I think you need to update your routes using the command `sonata:page:update-core-routes --site=all`

Answer (score 0):

Create your custom action, and register them in service, then add template and do all woth you need:
red off [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/cookbook/recipe_custom_action.html), it's help me

Comment: Thanks for repeating the documentation, but that doesn't really answer the question.